# What is the benefit of a talisman made from an ice troll's heart?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, rime-of-the-frostmaiden

*Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden* introduces [ice trolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/appendix-c-creatures#IceTroll) (p. 295), whose hearts can (among other uses) be transformed into a talisman that functions like a patch of brown mold. I don’t understand why you’d want this.

What is the benefit of a talisman made from an ice troll's heart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By my understanding, you are asking why such a talisman is special compared to any other talisman that you can theoretically make from anything. As the text you quoted contains, it functions like a patch of brown mold.

According to the DMG (p. 105), [brown mold](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/adventure-environments#BrownMold) is a hazard and has the following properties:

> Brown mold feeds on warmth, drawing heat from anything around it. A
> patch of brown mold typically covers a 10-foot square, and the
> temperature within 30 feet of it is always frigid.
>
> When a creature moves to within 5 feet of the mold for the first time
> on a turn or starts its turn there, it must make a DC 12 Constitution
> saving throw, taking 22 (4d10) cold damage on a failed save, or half
> as much damage on a successful one.
>
> Brown mold is immune to fire, and any source of fire brought within 5
> feet of a patch causes it to instantly expand outward in the direction
> of the fire, covering a 10-foot-square area (with the source of the
> fire at the center of that area). A patch of brown mold exposed to an
> effect that deals cold damage is instantly destroyed.

You could use this brown mold to lower the temperature in your immediate vicinity or you could use it as a sort of grenade. The possibilities are up to you, that is the beautiful thing about D&D :)

Comment: Maybe it's outside the scope of this particular question, but how would the expansion toward fire work if it's a talisman and not actually a patch of mold?

Comment: @ChumpNicholson I'd say Its up to the DM, but I would make it some sort of magical illusion expansion. Maybe that it looks like it's actually brown mold, but its only an illusion

Comment: I'm wondering if the item wasn't meant to say it functions like the first part, the temperature is always frigid within 30 feet, but doesn't grow or spread.  (The second part is iffy;  creatures immune to cold would love that, obviously.)